# Changing numbers inside list to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list wich contains numbers and other lists, and what I want is to change every number `x` to `{x,0}`.

So if the function I'm seeking is called `f`, then

```
a = {1,Pi,2+3I,{1,2},{3,4},-2}
```

`f[a]` should be `{{1,0},{Pi,0},{2+3I,0},{1,2},{3,4},{-2,0}}`.

I tried doing all kinds of rules, but none of them work as I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume the introduction of a sign in mapping of your last element from $2\to\{-2,0\}$ is a typo, should be $2\to\{2,0\}$ or $-2\to\{-2,0\}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`If[NumberQ[N[#]], {#, 0}, #] & /@ a`

or

`Replace[a, {b_ :> If[NumberQ[N[b]], {b, 0}, b]}, 1]`

or

`Replace[a, {b_ :> {b, 0} /; NumberQ[N[b]]}, 1]`

or

`a /. {{a_, b_} :> {a, b}, b_ :> {b, 0} /; NumberQ[N[b]]}`

or the above with `Element[b_,Complexes]` i.e.

`a /. {{a_, b_} :> {a, b}, b_ :> {b, 0} /; Element[b, Complexes]}`

or

`If[Element[#, Complexes] && !ListQ[#], {#, 0}, #] & /@ a`

or

`Replace[a, {b_ :> {b, 0} /; !ListQ[b] && Element[b, Complexes]}, 1]`

etc.

---

**Update:** Based on Alucard's nice comment.  If and only if elements strictly numbers or lists:

`Flatten@*List/@a//PadRight`

---

---

**Update${}^{\mathbf 2}$:** TIL: Besides brevity, Mr.Wizard's suggestion `NumericQ` definitely more efficient than `NumberQ@*N`.

Relatively inconsequential for simple numbers, but you can get creative:

```
someNumber = 
  Total[Table[(\[Pi] + I + GoldenAngle)^
      RandomInteger[{4, 
        1000}]/((\[Pi] - GoldenAngle + Exp[ I GoldenAngle])^
        RandomInteger[{4, 1000}] + (\[Pi] + GoldenAngle + 
          Exp[ I GoldenAngle])^RandomInteger[{4, 1000}]), {600}]];

RepeatedTiming[someNumber // N // NumberQ]
```

> {0.01, True}

```
RepeatedTiming[NumericQ@someNumber]
```

> {$2.3 \times 10^{-7}$, True}

Comment: I guess if you can really trust numbers xor lists as per taking strictly  "contains numbers and other lists" only really have to test for `ListQ`, i.e. `If[ListQ[#], #, {#, 0}] & /@ a`

Comment: or     If[ ListQ[#], #,  
       PadRight[{#}, 2]] & /@ a

Comment: I believe you can replace `NumberQ[N[#]]` with `NumericQ[#]` in each application.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help

```
PadRight[Charting`padList /@ a]
```

> `{{1,0},{π,0},{2+3 I,0},{1,2},{3,4},{-2,0}}`

Comment: 你总是能搞出些奇怪的函数，（手动滑稽。不知到SE上有没有这个问题：有哪些奇怪的函数不常见，但是挺有用？我没搜到，要是没有的话可以问一个。

Answer (score 3):

```
Transpose@Thread[PadRight[Flatten@*List /@ a]]
```

Answer (score 3):

- You only want to replace numeric things, not lists.
- You don't want to try to rewrite the entire list, just its elements, so you only want to replace subexpressions at level 1.

  Replace[a, b_?NumericQ -> {b, 0}, 1]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_]:={x,0}
f[{x___}]:={x}

f/@a

(*  {{1, 0}, {Pi, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: `x_` will capture standalone strings as well?

Comment: The OP has a list which "contains numbers and other lists".  If there are strings present (not specified), then this could be handled by (say) including `f[x_String]:=x` in the function definition

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, Pi, 2 + 3 I, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, -2};
```

First compare the outputs of `NumberQ` and `NumericQ` applied to the input list.

```
{#, NumberQ@#} & /@ a
```

> {{1, True}, {π, False}, {2 + 3 I, True}, {{1, 2}, False}, {{3, 4},
> False}, {-2, True}}

```
{#, NumericQ@#} & /@ a
```

> {{1, True}, {π, True}, {2 + 3 I, True}, {{1, 2}, False}, {{3, 4},
> False}, {-2, True}}

π is a symbol, but has a numeric value. Furthermore, to exclude lists, `Except` can be used.

```
Replace[a, Except[_List, x_?NumericQ] :> {x, 0}, 1]
```

> {{1, 0}, {π, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, Pi, 2 + 3 I, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, -2};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3}

```
SequenceReplace[a, {x_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0}]
```

{{1, 0}, {π,, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1}

```
SubsetReplace[a, {x_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0}]
```

{{1, 0}, {π,, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1}

```
ReplaceAt[x_?NumericQ :> {x, 0}, All] @ a
```

{{1, 0}, {π,, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, Pi, 2 + 3  I, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, -2};
```

Using `Cases` and `If`:

```
Cases[a, n_ :> If[ListQ[n], n, {n, 0}]]

(*{{1, 0}, {π, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}*)
```

Or using `Position` and `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[{#, 0} &, a, Rest@Position[a, n_ /; Head[n] =!= List, 1]]

(*{{1, 0}, {π, 0}, {2 + 3 I, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {-2, 0}}*)
```